# Jquery to set only one selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I'm using an html select from which i need to get only one selected value, while debugging using firebug i'd seen 2 options are selected.

How can make this mutually exclusive using a jquery? Please help

```
<select id="test" title="select table" class="selectChangeClass">
<option value="None">None</option>
<option value="Equal">Equal</option>
<option value="NotEqual">NotEqual</option>
<option value="LessThan">LessThan</option>
<option value="GreaterThan">GreaterThan</option>
<option value="LessthanOrEqual">LessthanOrEqual</option>
<option value="GreaterthanOrEqual">GreaterthanOrEqual</option>
</select>
```

- Script

  ```
   $('.selectChangeClass').live('change', function(event) {
      var changedText = $(this).val();
      var controlId = this.getAttribute('id');
          var indexSelected = this.selectedIndex;
          //
          this.selectedIndex = indexSelected;
          $('#test' option[value="' + changedText + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
          var opt = $('#' + controlId + ' option[value="' + changedText + '"]');
          var html = $("<div>").append(opt.clone()).html();
          html = html.replace(/\>/, ' selected="selected">');
          opt.replaceWith(html);


      });
  ```

Comment: Could you show us your html code?

Comment: How did you drawn options inside select tag.manual or php ?

Comment: @jSang please check the updated query

Comment: How are you getting the id? I don't see any id in your html select.

Comment: @JSang Actually, im dynamically generating the dropdown with the above options. I'd updated it now

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$("#selecID").change(function(e){
var selectedVal = $(this).val();
console.log(selectedVal);
});
```

**EDIT**

```
var selVal = $("#test :selected").val();
alert(selVal);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ftwG/)

also see this to how to change the selected option http://jsfiddle.net/9ftwG/1/

and this http://jsfiddle.net/9ftwG/4/ to see how to clone and change the selected option

Comment: this will return the value but wont set the option as selected.

Comment: the option is set as seleced if you post the form the selected value will be received

Comment: Only on posting? Do you know any jquery to search through the html options whether there is an item is already selected?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure i understand the issue. At what point are you getting two options selected? Is Multiple set on the select?

Here is a JSFiddle updating a div on change of a select: http://jsfiddle.net/aMs8G/.

Comment: im making the option as selected on change. I would like to know whether there is any simple jquery to make the selection mutually exclusive. I need the attribute 'selected' in my html. Please go through my query.

Comment: W3Schools is a low quality, junk filled tutorial site. The W3C define most web standards. They are **not** the same organisation.